# Changing a view's values and its layer's values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, cabasicanimation

I'm animating an ImageView using `CABasicAnimation`.
I move its layer to left, right, up and down and sometimes I'd scale it bigger then reset it to its original size etc.

I'm doing all this to its `layer` so I thought I might have to move & scale the real thing along with its `layer` as well but when I tested it with tap gesture to see if it really was just staying where it started, it wasn't. Therefore I no longer need to change its `view`'s frames as far as I'm concerned.

Is changing a view's layer's values also change its view's values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIView` is no more than a fancy wrapper for a `CALayer` – bringing `UIResponder` events & animation conveniences among *many* other things.

Many `UIView` properties are actually just forwarded versions of the underlying `CALayer` properties, defined purely for convenience.

- A view's `frame` & `bounds` properties should always reflect the layer equivalents.
- `transform` is slightly more complex, as for the view it's of type `CGAffineTransform` – whereas on the `layer` it's `CATransform3D`. If the layer's transform can be represented as a `CGAffineTransform`, then you'll be able to access it from the view after setting it on the layer. If it can't be represented, then its value is undefined.

Therefore yes, you are right in saying you don't need to update the `frame` or `transform` on the `UIView` when changing it on its `CALayer`. Although note that these properties won't reflect the 'in-flight' values of the animation – you'll need to access the layer's [`presentationLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) for that.

Also note that as @par & @jrturton mention, if a layer's transform is not the identity transform, then the `frame` is undefined and you therefore shouldn't use it.

Comment: Once you set a transform other than identity on a view or its layer the `frame` and `bounds` properties are no longer valid and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @par Yup, definitely a good point to include. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: `bounds`is still valid after transform. It's only `frame` that is undefined.

Comment: @jrturton Hmm... that's interesting. Always assumed that both would be undefined seeing how closely linked they are – but just tested, and you are indeed correct. The `bounds` is completely unaffected by the current `transform`. I have edited my answer.